# Super glue on fishing line

Tags: fishing

I want to know if it is better to use super glue to stable beads as stopper on the main line instead of rubber stoppers. Main line could be monofilament or fluorocarbon.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Super-glue is not water resistant. Better use epoxy. From  [this page :](https://powermodo.com/is-super-glue-waterproof-lets-find-out/)

> Actually, super glues are not waterproof, at best they can be said to
>   be water-resistant and will survive the occasional splash or brief
>   soak in water and still retain its bonding properties. This is chiefly
>   due to the fact that, the bond joint in a super glue will weaken and
>   break apart if it is constantly immersed or dipped in water.

Comment: Is there a possibility to weaken or damage the main line?

Comment: Epoxy resin is used as lining in aluminium bottles, fuel tanks etc. to protect it from corrosion. It will not chemically attack the line.